# Reverting to original state GSAP - TweenlineMax

Tags: css-animations, tween, gsap

I was looking through GSAP documentation and couldn't find a way to revert an animation to it's original state without going throught the whole reversed cycle. Basicly I want to Tween an element and after it ends I want it to jump back to it's original state without animation. Is there any good practice on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there are tons of ways:

```
timeline.seek(0).pause(); //jumps to the 0 position and then pauses
timeline.pause(0); //shortcut for the line above
timeline.progress(0).pause();
timeline.totalProgress(0).pause();
timeline.restart(0).pause();
```

(any single line above will do)

And "timeline" above is a reference to your TimelineMax instance. (you said "TweenlineMax" but I'm sure you meant TimelineMax).

Happy tweening!